# Finding cooling time using an impulse of heat energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, heat

> A chip has a thermal resistance of 0.007 K/J s and thermal capacitance
>   of 1.6 J/K. You give it an impulse of heat equal to 100 J. How long
>   does it take for the chip to cool to within 10% of the ambient
>   temperature?

I understand that I have to implement Newton's Law of Cooling, but I can't seem to grasp how I can find the ambient temperature nor the initial temperature.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the rise in temperature due to the applied impulse of 100 J?

Comment: No I do not know how.

Comment: Hi @blazinazian welcome to Physics.SE.  I've added the homework tag.  You need to explain a bit about what you've tried so we know how to help.  See our homework policy for more information: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 1):

Ambient temperature is taken to be 25 degree celsius (this is what they should mean)
Find the initial rise from:

Thermal capacitance * change in temperature = heat impulse

Gives change in temperature T. So the temperature of the chip is 25+T. They are asking when will this become 27.5 degree celsius (25 + 10% of 25). Use Newtons law of cooling, you are given the thermal resistance, to find out the time.